# json struct type loading to hive

Tags: json, hive

i have a json file like below and trying to get first_name from the transactions..

Json file:

```json
{"transNo_1":{"dataset1":{"first_name":"Ram1","last_name":"kumar1"}},"timestamp":"2023-06-09 12:11:20"}
{"transNo_2":{"dataset1":{"first_name":"Ram2","last_name":"kumar2"},"dataset2":{"first_name":"Ram3","last_name":"kumar3"}},"timestamp":"2023-07-09 12:12:20"}
```

not all transactions might have single dataset, and number of datasets can't be restricted..
i have already tried `get_json_object` and `regexp_replace`,

Expecting results like below:

`column1|column2`

`transNo_1|dataset1-ram1`

`transNo_2|dataset2-ram2,dataset2-ram3`